# Keep service alive in any mode in all version android

Tags: java, android, service

I know we can START_STICKY service or use receiver event for start service in android

I'm making chat app for android with java that this service must be active in
any mode in android

There are many method for keep alive this service
START_STICKY
Use phone event
Start Foreground

But I dont know what is best way for keep alive service and android 8 and  other version

You know that for chat app,service must be active always for receive new messages
Thanks

Comment: Run the service in a separate process and also use sticky BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: `"You know that for chat app,service must be active always for receive new messages "`, no, it does not have to be active - see [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: @pskink I dont want to use FCM

Comment: so you cannot have `"service alive in any mode in all version android"` - forget it - this is what FCM is for

Comment: @pskink OK,How do i use FCM for alive service? Send random push or schedule it?

Comment: @pskink I can use it ,I mean how do use it for alive service,You mean that i send message with FCM also?

Answer (score 1):

I found best solution

We dont have any problem about alive service in android 7 and lower version

Main problem is in android version 8

We can associate service to BroadcastReceiver in manifest and have alive service always

BroadcastReceiver can be TICK or CONNECTIVIYCHANGED or SCREEN event that when this events
occur so us service started without any problem

Thanks